Definition of electron-phonon matrix elements in PySCF
I am trying to get the matrix elements of the electron phonon interaction of molecules in PySCF. As a first step, I first run RHF to obtain the optimal orbitals. From here, I can get the matrix elements of the electron-phonon interaction using the EPH module (https://pyscf.org/user/eph.html).
As in the minimal example in the above link, I obtain the phonon frequencies (in $\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ I assume, since that is the units of the cut-off frequency) and electron-phonon matrix elements $E_{\alpha mn}$ where $\alpha$ labels the phonon modes and $mn$ label the orbitals.
My question is what is the convention for these matrix elements $E_{\alpha mn}$? I.e., if I have orbitals labelled by $m$ with creation operators $c_m^\dagger$, phonon modes labelled by $\alpha$ with creation operators $a_\alpha^\dagger$ and electron-phonon matrix elements $E_{\alpha mn}$, does the introduction of phonons lead to additional Hamiltonian terms of the form $$\sum_\alpha \hbar\omega_\alpha\left(a_\alpha^\dagger a_\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sum_{\alpha mn}E_{\alpha mn}\frac{a_\alpha^\dagger+a_\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}c_m^\dagger c_n?$$
Or is there another convention used?
